# Consensus and Execution don't sync anymore after restart

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

After put my private blockchain to run ( from https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/advanced/proof-of-stake-devnet ) I was happy because all was working very fine.

But after I stop my 3 containers: The Consensus (beacon), the validator and the geth (execution), it can't work anymore.

This is the log from the beacon:

```
time="2023-08-15 20:01:35" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=48 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:35" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=58 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:35" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=69 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:35" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=80 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:35" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=90 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=error msg="Could not compute head from new attestations" error="0x6bbafc6a869376dae39d15110c7eaa34670a6e41d0702ca5a61db08eb3d0222f: unknown justified root" prefix=blockchain
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=101 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=26 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=37 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=48 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=58 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=69 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=80 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
time="2023-08-15 20:01:36" level=debug msg="Can not process event" epoch=90 error="no peers available, waiting for reconnect" event=dataReceived prefix=initial-sync
```

The execution (GETH):

```
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.558] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=188  duration="115.518µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.559] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=189  duration="103.719µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.559] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=190  duration="114.591µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.559] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=191  duration="90.139µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.559] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=192  duration="101.94µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.560] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=193  duration="103.828µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.560] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=194  duration="99.987µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.560] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=195  duration="103.438µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.560] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=196  duration="105.762µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.560] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=197  duration="97.201µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.561] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=198  duration="104.037µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.561] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=199  duration="91.166µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.561] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=200  duration="101.64µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.561] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=201  duration="84.675µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.589] Served eth_getBlockByHash                conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=202  duration="156.984µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:10.620] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=203  duration="141.433µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:00:20.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:20.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=204  duration="119.407µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:23.277] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=205  duration="169.904µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:00:30.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:30.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=206  duration="137.762µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:36.504] Current full block not old enough        number=194      hash=147a57..afd32e delay=90000
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:37.277] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=207  duration="195.857µs"
WARN [08-15|20:00:38.633] Beacon client online, but no consensus updates received in a while. Please fix your beacon client to follow the chain! 
TRACE[08-15|20:00:40.514] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:40.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=208  duration="127.445µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:00:50.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:50.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=209  duration="169.626µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:00:51.277] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=210  duration="203.364µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:01:00.514] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:00.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=211  duration="116.204µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:05.277] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=212  duration="135.385µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:01:10.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:10.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=213  duration="267.144µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:10.516] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=214  duration="144.436µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:19.277] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=215  duration="145.134µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:01:20.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:20.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=216  duration="280.946µs"
TRACE[08-15|20:01:30.515] Engine API request received              method=ExchangeTransitionConfiguration ttd=0x0
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:30.515] Served engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=217  duration="109.517µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:33.276] Served eth_getBlockByNumber              conn=172.18.0.8:60906      reqid=218  duration="131.011µs"
DEBUG[08-15|20:01:36.505] Current full block not old enough        number=194      hash=147a57..afd32e delay=90000
```

And validator is just complaining `waiting for beacon to sync` forever...

Already done 5 fresh install, deleting all files and start over again. Same result everytime. I left the nodes running for 4 days and then restart to achieve same result.

The connectivity is alright. All are running inside same host Docker and I can see the consensus requesting data from the GETH.

What means `no peers available`? All 3 components are running like before... what new the consensus is waiting for?

I can't find any clue googling for these error messages.

What it can be wrong?